# How to determine what is more resource expensive, a write/read or a computation

Tags: database, performance, computer-science, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I scrape stock data. I scrape the following:

`opening price`, `stock price`, `volume traded`, `shares in issue`

The sites i scrape, also have a few other derived quantities available. By derived I mean these can be calculated from the quantities above. These include:

`value traded`, `market cap`, `price change`

Whilst the latter can just be scraped into my database and then read off later, I could also just write methods that calculate them on the fly when requested. So instead of writing them to database and reading later, I could just have methods like

`calculate_value_traded()`, `calculate_market_cap()` and `calculate_price_change()`

My question is, what is the more efficient way? How do i determine "more efficient" in practice? I know it may depend on amount of data being written/read and also nature of calculation but I am wondering how does one even benchmark which is more resource efficient and ultimately less expensive?

Am I looking at memory used, bandwidth, I/O or what? What would be the things i need to measure to ultimately choose one over the other?

Comment: You are using lots of different kinds of resources.  The one you probably didn't think of and that counts the most here is the number of dollars in your bank account.  The kind of data service and network plumbing that can provide you with that data at a rate that saturates the next one costs a *lot* of money.  So if you tinkered with this and nothing seems to make any difference then you found the true bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you need not store calculated values unless they are used extremly often or they should be provided extremly fast. The reason is that you have several places to make this calculations. First, it is database engine which usually has built-in possibility to work with calculated columns. Second, you may make calculations on your application client side thus redusing I/O as well as bandwidth. Both cases reduce your cost of storage which you should take into account as well. Third, you may use a kind of a cache storage for this data which uses for example IMDG storage.

Please, note that the answer is very general because we have no information on your performance and cost requirements as well as technical means which you are using.

But be aware of storing calculated data because you need implement mechanism to recalculate it when source data is updated to be sure that your data remains consistent.